# How to access a variable from another class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I'm trying to access a variable from another class via autowiring in Spring but I get a null pointer. The only way I can is by having it newly instantiated as static. Is there a way I can access it (the variable) in a non-static context - maybe something like autowiring?

Via static:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded {

    public static void setViews(Views aViews) {
        views = aViews;
    }

    private static Views views;
    .
    .
    .

    private void method() {
        views.thisVariable.....
    }
```

I'd like it somewhat like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded {

    @Autowired
    Views views;
    .
    .
    .

    private void method() {
        views.thisVariable.....
    }
```

Where the variable resides:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class Views extends ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded {


    ThisVariable thisVariable;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: What happens if you do as wanted @Autowired Views views ? The variable views remain unset?

Comment: Sorry, but why you need public class Views extends ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded ? Would not the class View alone be enough?

Comment: Could it be that you call the private void method() from ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded's constructor?

Comment: Would not pulling ThisVariable thisVariable  up trough the class hiearchy into the ClassWhereVariableIsNeeded be the simplest solution?

Comment: What does NOT work when you try to do it the way you want? Based on VERY limited information you gave here it should work...

Answer (score 0):

To access any variable and/or method you must set this variable/method access modifier higher than private.
private modifier restricts access to within the defining (or inner) class and nowhere else.
You can provide public/default/package (access) method for other classes to use/access your private variable

Comment: The variable is in default scope.

Comment: default access modifier is VERY restrictive, it is just a little more open than private...

Comment: The point is that the problem as stated in the question has nothing to do with variable scope.